# How To Change Port In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am confuse by this port,

so i have properties url like this

[image]

and then suddenly port 8801 is used by system, and i have to change it, and then i change it  in .csproj file

[image]

i change it, save it, reload project, not working

even when i change it to https://localhost:8808/TSICS, it still same, the properties not working, it still point to 8801 like image 1

where else should be changed to be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your asp.net project checked Configure for HTTPS, it will not work when you directly change the DevelopmentServerPort to the csproj file.

[image]

At this time, when you change the DevelopmentServerPort, you need to change the IISUrl at the same time (if you don't check Configure for HTTPS, you don't need to change the IISUrl at the same time).

[image]

After changing the DevelopmentServerPort and IISUrl at the same time, reload the project to change the URL.

[image]